# In mailing all recipients are not showing

Tags: groups, mailing

I have a problem related to 'mailings'. When I create a new mailing and select a group (for example, 'current members') in 'Recipients' then it is not showing all recipients. For example, I have 5681 total contacts, 67 of which are in 'Current Members' group, but after selecting this group in mailing it is showing only 4 recipients. I have checked there are not any blocked contacts and there are also not "Do Not Call" for any contact.

I am using following versions

CiviCRM Version 4.7.17
Wordpress Version 4.7.3

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, civicrm automatically excludes from the mailing recipients contacts that:

- have opted out (do not contact me)
- have bounced
- have said they do not want to receive emails

(I might miss a criteria or two)

Check some of your "vanished" contacts, the contact summary page should make clear why she isn't included.

Bounce emails is a common issue. It *might* be that you had a technical problem once and that your mail server wasn't willing to deliver the emails (eg. because you have a quota on how many emails you can send per hour) and were incorrectly flagged as bounce.

Comment: Where i check the "vanished" contacts?

Comment: search the contact in the groups that are not in the mailing recipinent and compare. I'm not sure I understood your question

Comment: I have already compare but not found any help

Comment: Please help me for this problem

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue today, and this fixed it - https://medium.com/@simonjohnparker/mosaico-civimail-all-recipients-not-showing-when-selecting-a-group-for-mailing-5c35c8232996

which links back to this:
[CiviMail Does Not Send To A Whole Group](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5086/civimail-does-not-send-to-a-whole-group)

Comment: See also https://civicrm.org/extensions/zombie-check